# ColdFusion: Reset JRun server

Tags: coldfusion, reset, railo, jrun

Is there a way to reset the JRun server from within a ColdFusion page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can restart any service you want. Just write a batch file and run with cfexecute.

```
<cfexecute name="#filepath#restartjrun.bat"></cfexecute>
```

In the batch file something like:

```
net stop "Macromedia JRun CFusion Server"
net start "Macromedia JRun CFusion Server"
```

As Ciaran mentioned though, it's always best to solve performance problems than rely of temporary fixes like this.

Comment: Good idea to get the job done, but does it depend on permissions of the user running CF? If it works it's like CF pulling the trigger on itself :-P

Comment: *If it works it's like CF pulling the trigger on itself*: Forcing your CF server to commit hara kiri. Talk about abuse. But seriously, even if it is possible, I too would question the reasons for wanting to do so

Comment: It would prolly be better to create an ASP/PHP page to do this.  Especially since I have found that if you need to restart the JRun service, a coldfusion page won't load anyway.

Comment: We have 2 instances of ColdFusion (subsite.website.com), and they very rarely seize up at the same time, I would put a page on the subsite to restart the main site and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that.

But just a suggestion if I may (and I don't mean to sound condescending here):

If you are trying to do a restart because of server performance I suggest you troubleshoot the real issue before even attempting to implement something like this.

- Check your exception logs
- Start using server monitoring
- Check system resources

See where that leads you.

We used to have to restart our CF servers a lot, but with careful understanding of the problems and subsequent fixing we would very rarely need to do that now.

I hope that helps.

Comment: But that is not really "fixing" the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfset myJrunObj = createObject("java", "jrunx.kernel.JRun")>
<cfset myJrunObj.restart(myJrunObj.getServerName())>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no for security reasons. It would be bad from a security stand point for an application to be able to modify the JVM that it was running in...